# android update: 4.4.2 change exifInterface always return 0

Tags: android, orientation

In my app i can select photos(portrait/landscape) and it used to show them in their original orientation with the help of this code:

```
public int getCameraPhotoOrientation(Context context, Uri imageUri, String imagePath) {
    int rotate = 0;
    context.getContentResolver().notifyChange(imageUri, null);
    File imageFile = new File(imagePath);

    try {
        ExifInterface exif;
        exif = new ExifInterface(imageFile.getAbsolutePath());
        int orientation = exif.getAttributeInt(
                ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION,
                ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL);
        System.out.println("ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION: "+ ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION
                + "\nExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL: " + ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL);
        switch (orientation) {
        case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270:
            rotate = 270;
            break;
        case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180:
            rotate = 180;
            break;
        case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90:
            rotate = 90;
            break;

        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return rotate;
}
```

i then updated my Sony phone to 4.4.2 and now its return value is always 0.
In my System.out.println, i check the orientation_normal and it is always 1 (landscape/portrait).
This is where i call the method:

```
            selectedImageUri = data.getData();
            screenShotUri = selectedImageUri;
            selectedImagePath = getPath(selectedImageUri);
            String fullPath = selectedImagePath;
            if (fullPath==null){
                return;
            }
            int index = fullPath.lastIndexOf("/");
            String fileNameUpperCase = fullPath.substring(index + 1);

            fileName = fileNameUpperCase.toLowerCase();

            pathTextView.setText("" + selectedImagePath);
            imageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            imageView.setImageURI(selectedImageUri);
            int rotate = controller.getCameraPhotoOrientation(this,
                    selectedImageUri, selectedImagePath);
```

here is where i rotate the photo:

```
if (rotate == 90) {
                Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
                matrix.postRotate(90);
                bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp, 0, 0, bmp.getWidth(),
                        bmp.getHeight(), matrix, true);
                imageView.setRotation(90f);
            } else if (rotate == 180) {
                Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
                matrix.postRotate(180);
                bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp, 0, 0, bmp.getWidth(),
                        bmp.getHeight(), matrix, true);
                imageView.setRotation(180f);
            } else if (rotate == 270) {
                Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
                matrix.postRotate(270);
                bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp, 0, 0, bmp.getWidth(),
                        bmp.getHeight(), matrix, true);
                imageView.setRotation(270f);
            }
```

Comment: `and now its return value is always 1`. Not possible. That function  can only return 0, 270, 180 and 90. Moreover you did not tell what it returned before kitkat.

Comment: you are right, it returns 0 but the ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL is always 1. Sorry about the confussion

Comment: Then please adapt your text.

Comment: That is a wrong edit. Your problem is (and you should tell so) that exif.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL) always returns 1. Well thats what you said it does. (Nobody sees that 1. Would that be ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_0 ?).  That you made another function around it is not relevant.